# I got semi-invisible Google Play 1-star rating

Tags: google-play-store

Recently I saw 1-star rating on an app. It was invisible to me when I selected any language other than English(US) in my phone. And the comment was empty.

[image: Image of ratings in Russian] [image: Image of ratings in English]
<sup>Image of rating in Russian / in English (click images for larger variants)</sup>

What to do with that. This is a bug?

Thanks!

P.S: Can't view the profile of that "Google user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment in Google Play store separate for different countries.

You can simply add to URL `&hl=en` where `en` is two-letter language code defined in [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

For example:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en
  (English)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=pl
  (Polish)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=it
  (Italian)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=fr
  (French)
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=es
  (Spanish)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11468716/5394817)

**What is a google user comment ?**

If we go through what is written [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/26/google-integration-for-play-store-reviews-is-live-all-previous-reviews-say-a-google-user/), we get that after updating review profile by user, play store simply replaces old user name by new entry *A Google User*. This can also be because of some reasons like reviewer changed his name or deleted his account.

[image: A google user]

Comment: Thanks for that. But I can't view the profile of "A Google user". Also, I did not have any ANR/crashes on Google Play Console mobile app.